# Understanding sed expression 's/^\.\///g'

Tags: linux, sed

I'm studying Bash programming and I find this example but I don't understand what it means:

```
filtered_files=`echo "$files" | sed -e 's/^\.\///g'`
```

In particular the argument passed to `sed` after '-e'.

Comment: If you want to know what `sed -e 's/^\.\///g'` does, that's purely a `sed` question, not a bash question at all -- `sed` would behave the same way if given the same arguments when using any shell, or no shell at all. For an example of that same effect with no shell involved, `subprocess.Popen(['sed', '-e', r's/^\.\///g']).communicate(files)` is an equivalent in Python.

Comment: It's also a poorly-written expression, and consequently something you shouldn't try to copy from when learning. If whoever wrote it instead wrote `s@^[.]/@@g`, that would be much easier to read. (Also, the `g` on the end is almost certainly a bug; when would you ever want to remove more than one `./` in a single path, unless you're putting multiple paths on a line in the variable -- which has its own set of bugs)?

Comment: ...anyhow, the right way to store a list of files would be in an array, not a single scalar variable, and to trim a leading `./` from all elements of an array is simply `filtered_files=( "${files[@]#./}" )` -- simpler and more correct, though (as before) it requires the starting variable to be an array, so you can't just drop it in without fixing the rest of your script first.

Comment: To understand _why_ you can't safely store a list of filenames in a scalar variable, by the way -- filenames can contain spaces. Filenames can contain newlines. Paths on UNIX can contain _any_ character other than NUL, and NUL can't exist in C-style strings (which are what bash uses), so storing a list of files in a scalar variable like this is buggy by definition.

Answer (score 5):

It's a bad example; you shouldn't follow it.

---

### First, understanding the sed expression at hand.

`s/pattern/replacement/flags` is the a `sed` command, described in detail in `man sed`. In this case, `pattern` is a regular expression; `replacement` is what that pattern gets replaced with when/where found; and `flags` describe details about how that replacement should be done.

In this case, the `s/^\.\///g` breaks down as follows:

- `s` is the `sed` command being run.
- `/` is the sigil used to separate the sections of this command. (Any character can be used as a sigil, and the person who chose to use `/` for this expression was, to be charitable, not thinking about what they were doing very hard).
- `^\.\/` is the pattern to be replaced. The `^` means that this replaces anything only at the beginning; `\.` matches only a period, vs `.` (which is regex for matching any character); and `\/` matches only a `/` (vs `/`, which would go on to the next section of this sed command, being the selected sigil).
- The next section is an empty string, which is why there's no content between the two following sigils.
- `g` in the `flags` section indicates that more than one replacement can happen each line. In conjunction with `^`, this has no meaning, since there can only be one beginning-of-the-line per line; further evidence that the person who wrote your example wasn't thinking much.

### Using the same data structures, doing it better:

All of the below are buggy when handling arbitrary filenames, because storing arbitrary filenames in scalar variables is buggy in general.

1. Still using `sed`:

   ```
   # Use printf instead of echo to avoid bugginess if your "files" string is "-n" or "-e"
   # Use "@" as your sigil to avoid needing to backslash-escape all the "\"s
   filtered_files=$(printf '%s\n' "$files" | sed -e 's@^[.]/@@g'`)
   ```
2. Replacing `sed` with a bash builtin:

   ```
   # This is much faster than shelling out to any external tool
   filtered_files=${files//.\//}
   ```

### Using better data structures

Instead of running

```
files=$(find .)
```

...instead:

```
files=( )
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  files+=( "$filename" )
done < <(find . -print0)
```

That stores files in an array; it looks complex, but it's far safer -- works correctly even with filenames containing spaces, quote characters, newline literals, etc.

Also, this means you can do the following:

```
# Remove the leading ./ from each name; don't remove ./ at any other position in a name
filtered_files=( "${files[@]#./}" )
```

This means that a file named

```
./foo/this directory name (which has spaces) ends with a period./bar
```

will correctly be transformed to

```
foo/this directory name (which has spaces) ends with a period./bar
```

rather than

```
foo/this directory name (which has spaces) ends with a periodbar
```

...which would have happened with the original approach.

Answer (score 0):

[`man sed`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/sed1.html).  In particular:

```
-e script, --expression=script
    add the script to the commands to be executed
```

And:

```
   s/regexp/replacement/
          Attempt  to match regexp against the pattern space.  If success-
          ful,  replace  that  portion  matched  with  replacement.    The
          replacement may contain the special character & to refer to that
          portion of the pattern space  which  matched,  and  the  special
          escapes  \1  through  \9  to refer to the corresponding matching
          sub-expressions in the regexp.
```

In this case, it replaces any occurence of `./` at the beginning of a line with the empty string, in other words removing it.

Comment: ok but things you say how are express in the code? for example what does mean 's' or 'g' or '///'?